# Will Allah forgive for dating a muslim guy?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I'm in a relationship with this muslim guy and we're from the same ethnicity and we do have plans for the future but I still don't know if what I'm doing is right...

Comment: A Muslim man who has plans for the future (with a girl) goes ahead and asks for the girl's hand in marriage from her father or guardian.

Comment: I sometime I ask myself which planet some muslims live in, answer is obvious its haram and sinful to mix with opposite gender.

Answer (score 1):

Allah swt is ar-Rahim. He is the most merciful and forgiving. This is one of the tricks of shaitan where he makes a person think that Allah will never forgive him or her for the sins they have commited. It's actually an insult to Allah swt because he is ar-rahim ( the most merciful) and al- ghafoor ( the all-forgiving).
Coming to your question..
In islam love before marriage is not haram but there are certain conditions also.There is nothing wrong in liking or loving someone, Allah swt has put this feeling within ourselves, but people often take this in a wrong direction. They go for outings,dates etc etc which is totally haram. If you are in a relationship with non-mehram then it is wrong. You should come out if it.  And if you both are genuine , meaning thinking of getting married in future then it will be better that you both make your relationship halal. If you both use to go for outings and dates then don't do it anymore just stop and repent to Allah swt. When a woman and a man are alone then the third party is shaitan with them. Ask that guy to talk to his parents and send you a proposal for marriage. Make halal easy . We make haram easy  therefore halal is like a hardship for us . Come closer to Allah, ask his forgiveness. He will surely forgive you if you are genuine. You can also do istikhara and you may ask Allah for his guidance. Indeed he will guide you towards the best. If that guy is good for you and for your akhirah Allah will make your relationship halal and if it's not then you will eventually start seeing negative points. You may see the way istikhara is done on google, various scholars have their videos on it.
May Allah swt forgive us and may he guide you to the straight path. Thankyou!

Answer (score -2):

Allah forgives any sin except shirk.So make your taubah and do not commite the same sin again.